# How to reference a column in the select clause in the order clause in SQLAlchemy like you do in Postgres instead of repeating the expression twice

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

In Postgres if one of your columns is a big complicated expression you can just say `ORDER BY 3 DESC` where 3 is the order of the column where the complicated expression is. Is there anywhere to do this in SQLAlchemy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Gord Thompson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2144390/gord-thompson) observes in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73953743/how-to-reference-a-column-in-the-select-clause-in-the-order-clause-in-sqlalchemy/73957107?noredirect=1#comment130589536_73957107), you can pass the column index as a text object to `group_by` or `order_by`:

```py
q = sa.select(sa.func.count(), tbl.c.user_id).group_by(sa.text('2')).order_by(sa.text('2'))
```

serialises to

```sql
SELECT count(*) AS count_1, posts.user_id 
FROM posts GROUP BY 2 ORDER BY 2
```

There are other techniques that don't require re-typing the expression.

You could use the [selected_columns](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/selectable.html?highlight=selected_columns#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Select.selected_columns) property:

```py
q = sa.select(tbl.c.col1, tbl.c.col2, tbl.c.col3)
q = q.order_by(q.selected_columns[2]) # order by col3
```

You could also order by a label (but this will affect the names of result columns):

```py
q = sa.select(tbl.c.col1, tbl.c.col2, tbl.c.col3.label('c').order_by('c')
```

Comment: I just tried `q = sa.select(tbl.c.id, tbl.c.txt).order_by(sa.text("2"))` and when I `print(q)` I see `SELECT tbl.id, tbl.txt FROM tbl ORDER BY 2`.

Comment: @GordThompson haha I didn't think of ordering by  text object :-)